# Community with external auth provider

Tags: oauth2, community

We are trying to configure a community site with external auth provider.
We have a c# service that connects between an SSO service we have that is working with open id protocol and salesforce. This service is set as the external login/register.
In the service, we see that we return an access token:

https://test.salesforce.com/services/authcallback/00Dm00000002HnQEAU/GM_sso?code=MmMzZjBjNTQtM2U5My00OGQyLTgxZmYtMjVmZjc3MTRjNzg0&response_type=code&client_id=gmsso&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2ftest.salesforce.com%2fservices%2fauthcallback%2f00Dm00000002HnQEAU%2fGM_sso&scope=openid&state=ut5%2bfM70dkBCn7adfjXVA6BjRZB%2f5LrPa5Eg%2bGw4MAQdGSIAj7KdREAzJh2JkkafeORTZjSwVm0MxB7Q5NjlaVPKb1GoMfroOkMRYSrmBUQp7T24taic0Dy28e%2fb6AyB4oWq%2brl0J%2b%2fRQTHpAfDt2l79bEXOSfCgBbOiBKPJaaGA13PAF3ZHKuri0%2bCtxDCJoXU%2fenHlDYDWFXPfFFX0JWFz4fCPO9hz1EGCsL7JTo9wcMZox47TsE7h5x84IjyWAMI%3d

But the page we get to shows this error:

Error
There was a problem with your authentication attempt. Please try again. If you continue to encounter problems, contact your administrator.

And the url shows this error:

AuthorizationError?ErrorCode=No_Oauth_Token&ErrorDescription=Access+token+was+not+returned

Do you have any idea on how to continue from here?

Thanks.